# How to solve this probability problem using events

Tags: probability

Here is the problem with the work I've done with each question.

```
There is work to do on a building. The jobs will be done by guy A or guy B.     
The probability that A is available is 0.65.     
The probability that B will be available is 0.70.     
The probability that none of the two guys will be available is 0.2.
```

- Let A be the event "guy A is available"
- Let B be the event "guy B is available"
- Let N be the event "None available"

**A) Find the probability that both of the guys will be available. Show it with events.**

$P(A|\bar{N}) * P(B|\bar{N}) = 0.65*0.8 * 0.7*0.8 = 0.29 $

My reasoning behind this is : I want the opposite of N, multiplied by the prop. of A and B, and then I put those together.

**B) Find the probability that at least one guy will be available.**

$1 - P(\bar{A}|N) * P(\bar{B}|N) = 0.35*0.2 + 0.3*0.2 = 0.13$

$ 1-0.13 = 0.87  $

My reasoning behind this is : 1 - the probability that none are available.

**C) Find the probability that one and only one will be available.**

$P(A|\bar{N}) * P(\bar{B}|\bar{N}) + P(\bar{A}|\bar{N}) * P(B|\bar{N})$

$0.65*0.8 * 0.3*0.8 + 0.35*0.8 * 0.7*0.8 = 0.28$

Thoughts : probab of A avail. and B not + probab of B avai. and A not.

**D) Find the probability that guy B will be available, knowing that A is not available.**

Well... I could use some help to do this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would draw a Venn diagram

[image]

**B) Find the probability that at least one guy will be available.**

You just want

$$P(A \cup B) = 1 - P(N)$$

I agree with your reasoning "1 $-$ the probability that none are available" here but not your answer.

**A) Find the probability that both of the guys will be available. Show it with events.**

You want $P(A\cap B)$, which I have written $P(AB)$ on my diagram, given by

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$$

rearranging this equation gives

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)$$

you can also substitute $P(A \cup B) = 1 - P(N)$ from part B, above, to express $P(A\cap B)$ directly in terms of the probabilities you are given in the question

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A) + P(B) + P(N) - 1$$

**C) Find the probability that one and only one will be available.**

You want A or B but not both

$$P(A \cup B) - P(AB)$$

**D) Find the probability that guy B will be available, knowing that A is not available.**

This is [conditional probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Kolmogorov_definition), so you can't just rely on the diagram: you need the formula.

$$P(B|\neg A) = \frac{P(B \cap \neg A)}{P(\neg A)}$$

You can use the diagram to get the numerator and the denominator.

$$P(B \cap \neg A) = P(B) - P(AB)$$

and

$$P(\neg A) = 1 - P(A)$$

**Commentary on conditional probability**

[David's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/663922/77151) makes some great points about conditional probability and dependence of events in general, which I will not rehearse again here. Suffice to say that I agree that a simple approach is possible for the first three questions.

Comment: I'm confuse about $P(AB)$. What is it ? Reading online and with david's answer, I see that I can't assume $P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$ because I dont know if they are independant. I'm trying to figure out what does $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(AB)$ result in numbers. I have $0.65 + 0.70 - P(AB)$ Does $P(AB) = 0.455$ ? If so then I have a probability of $0.90$ that both of them will be available... which makes me suspicious.

Comment: @Dave sorry I should have said, $P(AB)=P(A\cap B)$, will amend my answer (I just couldn't easily use the symbol $\cap$ in my drawing program). And yes, $P(AB)=P(A)P(B)$ **if and only if** events A and B are independent. To get $P(AB)$ you need to rearrange the equation I wrote: I will add that to my answer. If you want to give your answers for parts 1 to 4 I'm happy to comment further (I don't think 0.455 is correct).

Comment: @Dave another idea is that you could draw a Venn diagram, with rectangles rather than circles, on graph paper, allocating, say, one square = 0.05 probability (this is enough resolution to get the first 3 answers). You should find that with the values for A,B,N given you are forced to have a certain overlap between A and B. You can then count squares to check on your calculations and this exercise might also give you some more intuition for what's happening.

Comment: Ok so for A I have 0.55%, B 80 %, C 25 %. Now I'm wondering if it makes sense to assume that 1 - 0.2 is the probability that at least one will be available.

Comment: @Dave I agree with those answers. You should be able to draw the Venn diagram on graph paper with those numbers and see that it all works (11 squares for part 1, 16 for part 2 and 5 for part 3). What do you get for D?

Comment: I get 43 % for D. I'll be honest here. I don't understand everything that's going on but I'm going to do the graph paper later on today to get a better intuition as you suggested.

Comment: @Dave that matches my calculations. Seems like you've got it!

Answer (score 1):

You are using conditional probability notation for your answers.  I'm not sure if that's what you actually meant, as none of the three answers involves conditional probability at all.

Conditional probability is used in the situation where you already have some information about what has happened, and you want to calculate a probability which takes that into account.  The word normally used is "given", as in "find the probability that A occurs, given that B has occurred".  Other terminology can be used, and in fact "knowing" in your fourth question serves the same purpose: it could be rephrased as "find the probability that B is available, given that A is not available".  So (D) is in fact a conditional probability question.

Actually (B) is the easiest question: your reason is correct, but where did the number $0.13$ come from? - the probability that none is available is given and you don't need to calculate it.

The simplest way to visualise (A), (B) and (C) is to draw a Venn diagram.  You should also know the "inclusion/exclusion" formula
$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\ .$$
This together with your answer to (B) will give $P(A\cap B)$, which will be the answer to (A).  For (C) your idea is correct but the numbers are wrong.

Note that you *cannot* always multiply probabilities: the formula
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$
is true only if $A$ and $B$ are independent.  You should never assume two events are independent unless you have a specific reason for it.  In this case it is very easy to imagine that the availabilities of A and B are *not* independent: if there is a lot of building work going around then probably both will be unavailable, while if there is not much then probably both will be available.

The conditional probability formula is
$$P(X|Y)=\frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(Y)}$$
and once you identify what you mean by $X$ and $Y$, this is what you need for (D).  Good luck!

Comment: My answer's more pictorial than yours and hopefully complementary. However I'm not sure I agree that the OP's answer to part B is correct: surely P(at least one) = 1 - P(none)?

Comment: Sorry, somehow I managed to misread the figures.  The OP's reason is correct but the number is wrong.  Answer amended.  Thanks